# Multiline CSV file to matrix in C

Tags: c, csv, file-io, matrix, type-conversion

I'm writing program to count scores.

The input file `full list.txt` looks like:

```
123456,11,24,,51,,12,,76,,,531,12,,,,24,56,,,,,118,,,,,,,,,,,,,,20,,,,,
123456,11,24,,51,,12,,76,,,531,12,,,,24,56,,,,,118,,,,,,,,,,,,,,20,,,,,
123456,11,24,,51,,12,,76,,,531,12,,,,24,56,,,,,118,,,,,,,,,,,,,,20,,,,,
123456,11,24,,51,,12,,76,,,531,12,,,,24,56,,,,,118,,,,,,,,,,,,,,20,,,,,
...
123456,11,24,,51,,12,,76,,,531,12,,,,24,56,,,,,118,,,,,,,,,,,,,,20,,,,,
```

The first number is ID, rest are scores. I was trying to put this file to matrix of c[42][1000] to count the total scores and arrange them in increasing order... But the problem I've faced is:
The program only counts the 1st line so far....
Any ideas how to make it store all of them?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)

    {
    int lines_allocated = 1000;
    int max_line_len = 150;
    double c[42][1000];
    char **words = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*)*lines_allocated);
    if (words==NULL)
        {
        fprintf(stderr,"Out of memory (1).\n");
        exit(1);
        }

    FILE *fp = fopen("full list.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error opening file.\n");
        exit(2);
        }

    int i;
    for (i=0;1;i++)
        {
        int j;

        if (i >= lines_allocated)
            {
            int new_size;

            new_size = lines_allocated*2;
            words = (char **)realloc(words,sizeof(char*)*new_size);
            if (words==NULL)
                {
                fprintf(stderr,"Out of memory.\n");
                exit(3);
                }
            lines_allocated = new_size;
            }
        words[i] = (char*)malloc(max_line_len);
        if (words[i]==NULL)
            {
            fprintf(stderr,"Out of memory (3).\n");
            exit(4);
            }
        if (fgets(words[i],max_line_len-1,fp)==NULL)
            break;

        for (j=strlen(words[i])-1;j>=0 && (words[i][j]=='\n' || words[i][j]=='\r');j--)
            ;
        words[i][j]='\0';
        }

    int j;
    int k=i;
    for(j = 0; j < k; j++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", words[j]);
        char *pptr = words[j];
        int l;
        words[j][strlen(words)-1]=',';
        for (l = 0; l < 41; l++)
        {
            char *ptr = strchr(pptr, ',');
            if (ptr) 
            {
                *ptr = 0;
                c[l][j] = atof(pptr);
                pptr = ptr + 1;
            }
        }
        for (l = 0; l < 41; l++)
        {
            printf("%.2lf\n", c[l][j]);
        }
        return 0;
    }


    for (;i>=0;i--)
    free(words[i]);
    free(words);
    return 0;
    }
```

May be the matrix doesn't store any value at all.

Comment: _The program only counts the 1st line_ ,  `return 0;` in loop. also typo `words[j][strlen(words)-1]=',';`

Comment: Now it does not store the value after last comma :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BLUEPIXY, thanks for attention, solved =)

Was extra `return 0`.

However:

`words[j][strlen(words)-1]=',';`

or

`words[j][strlen(words[j])-1]=',';`

Does not affect the matrix. I have no idea why it does not, but it should, shouldn't it?

Final code is following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)

    {
    int lines_allocated = 1000;
    int max_line_len = 150;
    double c[42][1000];
    char **words = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*)*lines_allocated);
    if (words==NULL)
        {
        fprintf(stderr,"Out of memory (1).\n");
        exit(1);
        }

    FILE *fp = fopen("full list.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error opening file.\n");
        exit(2);
        }

    int i;
    for (i=0;1;i++)
        {
        int j;

        if (i >= lines_allocated)
            {
            int new_size;

            new_size = lines_allocated*2;
            words = (char **)realloc(words,sizeof(char*)*new_size);
            if (words==NULL)
                {
                fprintf(stderr,"Out of memory.\n");
                exit(3);
                }
            lines_allocated = new_size;
            }
        words[i] = (char*)malloc(max_line_len);
        if (words[i]==NULL)
            {
            fprintf(stderr,"Out of memory (3).\n");
            exit(4);
            }
        if (fgets(words[i],max_line_len-1,fp)==NULL)
            break;

        for (j=strlen(words[i])-1;j>=0 && (words[i][j]=='\n' || words[i][j]=='\r');j--)
            ;
        words[i][j]='\0';
        }

    int j;
    int k=i;
    for(j = 0; j < k; j++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", words[j]);
        char *pptr = words[j];
        int l;
        words[j][strlen(words)-1]=',';
        for (l = 0; l < 42; l++)
        {
            char *ptr = strchr(pptr, ',');
            if (ptr) 
            {
                *ptr = 0;
                c[l][j] = atof(pptr);
                pptr = ptr + 1;
            }
        }    
    }

    int l;
    for (j = 0; j < k; j++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for (l = 0; l < 42; l++)
        {
            printf("%.2lf\t", c[l][j]);
        }
    }
    for (;i>=0;i--)
    free(words[i]);
    free(words);
    return 0;
}
```

However, now the problem is the value after last comma does not included to array....

Comment: `words[j][strlen(words[j])-1]=',';` is last comma replace comma. no   effect.